# Problema al cambiar propiedades CSS con javascript

Tags: javascript

**EDITO:
El problema venía que la consulta a la base de datos me estaba cogiendo la información de otro usuario, no del que había iniciado sesión. Fallo absurdo, lo he solucionado haciendo una consulta aparte sabiendo que esa variable sólo la estoy usando para el script de cambio de colores.**

Buenas,

Me estoy encontrado con un problema en javascript al querer modificar las propiedades CSS en fundíón de unos valores que indique el usuario, y no le encuentro ningún sentido a lo que hace. Por defecto tengo ya unas propiedades CSS aplicadas, pero esas propiedades se pueden modificar, y en función de esos nuevos colores, quiero que se cambie el diseño de la web (colores).

Hay elementos que aparecen más de una vez, en distintas secciones, pero que  en teoría con ejecutar el mismo comando debería hacer lo mismo, pero me he encontrado con un caso que no lo hace.

El script es el siguiente:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var color_fuerte = "#<?php echo $user['color_principal'] ?>";
var color_medio = "#<?php echo $user['color_secundario'] ?>";
var color_suave = "#<?php echo $user['color_fondo'] ?>";


var botones = document.getElementsByClassName("crear_hilo").length

if (botones > 0) {

    var array_botones = new Array('crear_hilo', 'fa-search');

    for (var i = 0; i < array_botones.length; i++) {
        var d = document.getElementsByClassName(array_botones[i]).length;
        for (var j=0; j<d; j++) {
            document.getElementsByClassName(array_botones[i])[j].style.background = color_medio;
        }
    }

}

</script>
```

No tiene mucha intriga, primero compruebo si existe el elemento con `var botones = document.getElementsByClassName("crear_hilo").length`, si me da una longitud significa que el elemento existe, entonces es cuando hago los cambios. Como hay cosas que implican otras, es decir, siempre que tengo el botón con la clase "crear_hilo" siempre tengo un icono de buscador, por eso incluyo luego un array para recorrer individualmente estos elementos y modificar sus propiedades.

El caso es que tengo la clase "crear_hilo" dos veces, en distintas secciones, y curiosamente en la primera SÍ que funciona, y en la segunda NO me funciona, me cambia el estilo, pero al que ya tiene por defecto, cosa que no le veo ni pies ni cabeza...Si por ejemplo en vez de la variable `valor_medio` uso directamente su valor, es decir `document.getElementsByClassName(array_botones[i])[j].style.background = "rgb(194, 104, 104)";`, se cambian las 2 clases, pero evidentemente no puedo hacer eso porque quiero que se modifique en función del color elegido por el usuario. En la consola no me da ningún error, pero no entiendo dónde está el problema.

Dejo también la parte del código HTML:

```
 echo "<div class='creacion_hilo'>";

                if (isset($_SESSION['usuario'])) {
                    echo "<a class='crear_hilo' href='crear_hilo.php?foro=" . str_replace(" ", "%",$foro) . "&subforo=" . $subforo ."'>+ CREAR HILO</a>";
                } else {
                    echo "<p class='crear_hilo no_sesion'>+ CREAR HILO</p>";
                }

                echo "<div class='busqueda_hilo'>";
                    echo "<input type='text' name='search_hilo' placeholder='Buscar en este foro...'>";
                    echo "<label class='fa fa-search' for='search_hilo'></label>";
                echo "</div>";
 echo "</div>";
```

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta porque parece ser un problema que no se puede reproducir o un error tipográfico (como el propio usuario indica en una edición).

Comment: La he votado también para cierre. Cuando te vuelva a ocurrir algo así podrás darte cuenta del error verificando los valores que te están fallando, en este caso el primer paso era verificar lo que había en la variable `var color_medio`. Cuando hay errores es bueno depurar en orden de prioridad, empezando por lo más básico.

Answer (score 0):

debes arreglar algunas cosas.

```
<script type="text/javascript">


var clases = new Array('creacion_hilo', 'fa-search');
var panel = document.getElementsByClassName(clases[0])

if (panel.length > 0) {

    for (var i = 0; i < panel.length; i++) {
        var botones = panel[i].getElementsByClassName(clases[1]);
        for (var j = 0; j < botones.length; j++) {
            botones[j].style.backgroundColor = "red"; // tu variable.
        }
    }

}
</script>
```